# can not receive emails by mail function of php?

Tags: php, email, xampp, localhost, sendmail.exe

I want to send email on my localhost via mail function of php,I have a file which includes html and php within it,the .html file is loaded by xampp on my localhost,and when clicking on "send mail" button I receive the "email is sent" comment,but it is not actually received in my inbox.

the .html file is

```
<?php

if (!isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  ?>
    <form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

    Your name:<br> 
    <input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 
    Your email:<br> 
    <input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 

    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit"/> 
    </form> 
    <?php 
    }  
else               
    { 
    $name=$_REQUEST['name']; 
    $email=$_REQUEST['email']; 

    if (($name=="")||($email=="")) 
        { 
        echo "All fields are required."; 
        } 
    else{         

        $message=$name.''.$email; 
        $subject="Data of users";       
        $sent=mail("farnam7022@yahoo.com", $subject, $message); 
    if($sent)
        { echo "Email sent!"; }
    else
        { echo "We encountered an error sending your mail"; }

        } 
    }   
?>
```

and this is sendmail.in:

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=farnam70422@gmail.com
auth_password=**** //my password
force_sender=farnam70422@gmail.com
```

and this is php.in

```
[PHP]


engine=On


short_open_tag=Off

asp_tags=Off


precision=14


y2k_compliance=On


output_buffering=4096


zlib.output_compression=Off


implicit_flush=Off


unserialize_callback_func=


serialize_precision=100


allow_call_time_pass_reference=Off


safe_mode=Off


safe_mode_gid=Off


safe_mode_include_dir=


safe_mode_exec_dir=


safe_mode_allowed_env_vars=PHP_


safe_mode_protected_env_vars=LD_LIBRARY_PATH



disable_functions=


disable_classes=


zend.enable_gc=On


expose_php=On


max_execution_time=30


max_input_time=60


memory_limit=128M


error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT


display_errors=On


display_startup_errors=On


log_errors=On


log_errors_max_len=1024


ignore_repeated_errors=Off


ignore_repeated_source=Off


report_memleaks=On


track_errors=On


html_errors=On


error_log="E:\Xamp\php\logs\php_error_log"

variables_order="GPCS"


request_order="GP"


register_globals=Off


register_long_arrays=Off


register_argc_argv=Off


auto_globals_jit=On


post_max_size=8M


magic_quotes_gpc=Off


magic_quotes_runtime=Off


magic_quotes_sybase=Off


auto_prepend_file=


auto_append_file=


default_mimetype="text/html"


include_path=".;E:\Xamp\php\PEAR"

doc_root=


user_dir=


extension_dir="E:\Xamp\php\ext"


enable_dl=On


upload_tmp_dir="E:\Xamp\tmp"


upload_max_filesize=2M


max_file_uploads=20


allow_url_fopen=On


allow_url_include=Off


default_socket_timeout=60



extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll

extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll

extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll

extension=php_openssl.dll

extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll

extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll

extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_sockets.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll

extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
extension=php_xsl.dll



[CLI Server]

cli_server.color=On

[Date]

date.timezone=Europe/Berlin


[filter]

[iconv]

[intl]

[sqlite]

[sqlite3]

[Pcre]

[Pdo]

[Pdo_mysql]

pdo_mysql.cache_size=2000


pdo_mysql.default_socket="MySQL"

[Phar]


[Syslog]

define_syslog_variables=Off

[mail function]
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = farnam70422@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"E:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

mail.add_x_header=Off


[SQL]
sql.safe_mode=Off

[ODBC]
odbc.allow_persistent=On

odbc.check_persistent=On

odbc.max_persistent=-1

odbc.max_links=-1

odbc.defaultlrl=4096

odbc.defaultbinmode=1


[Interbase]
ibase.allow_persistent=1

ibase.max_persistent=-1

ibase.max_links=-1

ibase.timestampformat="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

ibase.dateformat="%Y-%m-%d"

ibase.timeformat="%H:%M:%S"

[MySQL]
mysql.allow_local_infile=On

mysql.allow_persistent=On

mysql.cache_size=2000

mysql.max_persistent=-1

mysql.max_links=-1

mysql.default_port=3306

mysql.default_socket="MySQL"

mysql.default_host=

mysql.default_user=

mysql.default_password=

mysql.connect_timeout=3

mysql.trace_mode=Off

[MySQLi]

mysqli.max_persistent=-1

mysqli.allow_local_infile=On

mysqli.allow_persistent=On

mysqli.max_links=-1

mysqli.cache_size=2000

mysqli.default_port=3306

mysqli.default_socket="MySQL"

mysqli.default_host=

mysqli.default_user=

mysqli.default_pw=

mysqli.reconnect=Off

[mysqlnd]
mysqlnd.collect_statistics=On

mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics=Off


[OCI8]


[PostgresSQL]
pgsql.allow_persistent=On

pgsql.auto_reset_persistent=Off

pgsql.max_persistent=-1

pgsql.max_links=-1

pgsql.ignore_notice=0

pgsql.log_notice=0

[Sybase-CT]
sybct.allow_persistent=On

sybct.max_persistent=-1

sybct.max_links=-1

sybct.min_server_severity=10

sybct.min_client_severity=10


[bcmath]
bcmath.scale=0

[browscap]
browscap="E:\Xamp\php\extras\browscap.ini"

[Session]
session.save_handler=files

session.save_path="E:\Xamp\tmp"

session.use_cookies=1

session.use_only_cookies=0

session.name=PHPSESSID

session.auto_start=0

session.cookie_lifetime=0

session.cookie_path=/

session.cookie_domain=

session.cookie_httponly=

session.serialize_handler=php

session.gc_probability=1

session.gc_divisor=1000

session.gc_maxlifetime=1440

session.bug_compat_42=On

session.bug_compat_warn=On

session.referer_check=

session.entropy_length=0

session.entropy_file=

session.cache_limiter=nocache

session.cache_expire=180

session.use_trans_sid=0

session.hash_function=0

session.hash_bits_per_character=5

url_rewriter.tags="a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"


[MSSQL]
mssql.allow_persistent=On

mssql.max_persistent=-1

mssql.max_links=-1

mssql.min_error_severity=10

mssql.min_message_severity=10

mssql.compatability_mode=Off

mssql.secure_connection=Off


[Assertion]

[COM]

[mbstring]

[gd]

[exif]

[Tidy]
tidy.clean_output=Off

[soap]
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1

soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"

soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400

soap.wsdl_cache_limit=5

[sysvshm]

[ldap]
ldap.max_links=-1

[mcrypt]

[dba]

[FrontBase]

[mime_magic]
mime_magic.magicfile="E:\Xamp\php\extras\magic.mime"

[eAccelerator]
eaccelerator.shm_size="0"

eaccelerator.cache_dir="E:\Xamp\tmp"

eaccelerator.enable="1"

eaccelerator.debug=0

eaccelerator.check_mtime="1"

eaccelerator.filter=""

eaccelerator.shm_max="0"

eaccelerator.shm_ttl="0"

eaccelerator.shm_prune_period="0"

eaccelerator.shm_only="0"

[XDebug]
```

by the way,xampp is using port 85,and the windows is 7,and the xampp version is 1.8.2.2

any help would be so appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. I've reproduced it and everything worked OK.

Check your junk folder, maybe the message didn't even reach because the IP of the mail server was banned.

---

There could be something wrong with your server configuration, I do not know. 
Eventually you can try to add this code to the beginning of your script:

```
<?php ini_set("sendmail_form", "info@mydomain.com"); ?>
```

And read `mail()` functions requirements:

> For the Mail functions to be available, **PHP must have access to the
>   sendmail binary on your system** during compile time. If you use another
>   mail program, such as qmail or postfix, be sure to use the appropriate
>   sendmail wrappers that come with them. PHP will first look for
>   sendmail in your PATH, and then in the following:
>   /usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/etc:/etc:/usr/ucblib:/usr/lib. It's highly
>   recommended to have sendmail available from your PATH. Also, the user
>   that compiled PHP must have permission to access the sendmail binary.